# dirtied inode

Tags: ext3, inode

I am investigating a very strange io issue. I have vm.block_dump enabled and I am seeing allot of messages in this form:

process(29177): dirtied inode 42254471 (filename) on 0:14

What does dirtied inode mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common computer term that data in a cache is "clean" when it has been synchronized, and "dirty" when it is different.

A dirty inode has had new data written into it but it has not been written to disk.